# add code with php script to a certain div

Tags: php, html, forms

I have written an html form in my template.php and I have the script.php like this:

```
<?php
include "index.php";
if (isset($_GET['numOfPictures'])){ 
    $times = $_GET['numOfPictures'];
    echo '<form name="upload" action="code.php" method="POST">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
        echo '<br />select picture number '.$i.': <br />';
        echo '<input name="file'.$i.'" type="file" />';                     
    }
    echo '</br><input name="submitFiles" type="submit" />'; 
    echo '</form>';             
}
?>
```

When I submit my 3 number option selection form, I want to append in the same DIV. Afterwards, the PHP script I wrote then adds another form to the code.
What happens in my page is that the script adds the new form in the end of the page.
How do I do that?

I don't want to do the code inside my template.php, I want to keep them separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign all the html you build your form with to a variable.

```
$form = '';
if (isset($_GET['numOfPictures'])){ 
    $times = $_GET['numOfPictures'];
    $form .= '<form name="upload" action="code.php" method="POST">';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $times; $i++){
        $form .= ' '<br />select picture number '.$i.': <br />';
        $form .= ' '<input name="file'.$i.'" type="file" />';                     
    }
    $form .= ' '</br><input name="submitFiles" type="submit" />'; 
    $form .= ' '</form>';             
}
```

You now have a variable you can use any where in your template.php. You might want to add something like this to your template file

```
<div>
    <?php
    if (isset($form) && $form !== '') {
        echo $form;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Just make sure you create the $form variable before including your template.php file